Adding elements into an array using Powershell
I have created an array to store elements of Ids of a Get-Process request.
$arr = [int64[]]::new(1000);
Here is the code to output the data
$process = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.handles -gt 1000}

I want to select the column for IDs specifically, and here is the code below
$a = $process | Select-Object -Property Id

My question now is how do you store the data for $a inside the $arr

$a = $process.ID gives you an array of process ID values. In a pipeline you can also use $process | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ID or $process | ForEach-Object ID.

.. and if you want these values to become Int64, just do $a = [int64[]]$process.Id. What would be the point of creating a thousand item array and then trying to insert values into that afterwards?

As one-liner: $a = [int64[]](Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.handles -gt 1000}).Id

Why do you want to create the array and populate it as two steps? You can just cast the result of the pipeline to int64[].
But Select-Object -property Id doesn't get you a value you can cast to int64, so that will never work. You can just use ForEach-Object { $_.Id } instead, however.
 $arr = [int64[]](Get-Process |
         Where-Object { $_.handles -gt 1000 } | 
         ForEach-Object  { $_.Id })


Or, more simply: [int64[]] (Get-Process | Where-Object Handles -gt 1000  | ForEach-Object  Id or even [int64[]] (Get-Process | Where-Object Handles -gt 1000).Id or, also for better performance, [int64[]] (Get-Process).Where({ $_.Handles -gt 1000 }).Id
